# Reordering Plot and Changing Axis Size (R ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to change in both of my plots, the order and the x axis size for both. These are not being able to be changed accordingly

## DF Creation

```
contig_count_average <- data.frame(Genome_Type = c("MBT", "Anglucyclines", "Whole Genome"),
                                   Contig_Count_Average = c("2.91","83.7","608.3"))
```

## Plot

```
p2 <- ggplot(contig_count_average, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Genome_Type, Contig_Count_Average), Contig_Count_Average, fill = Genome_Type))  + 
  xlab("Genome") +
  ylab("Contig No.") + 
  ggtitle("Contig Count per Genome Distribution") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=20),
       axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Genome Type")) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2835), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)
p
```

I get the following warning:

```
1: In Ops.factor(Contig_Count_Average) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

Comment: Do `contig_count_average <- type.convert(contig_count_average, as.is = TRUE)` and run the code again. Or `contig_count_average$Contig_Count_Average <- as.numeric(as.character(contig_count_average$Contig_Count_Average))` to change class of only one column.

Comment: yes, this did the trick. I'm still having an issue with the text size. I don't know why it won;t change :S

Comment: fixed it by just adding the theme addtionally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because `Contig_Count_Average` is treated as factors in `contig_count_average`.

We can change it to numeric by doing either :

```
contig_count_average <- type.convert(contig_count_average, as.is = TRUE
```

Or

```
contig_count_average$Contig_Count_Average <- as.numeric(as.character(contig_count_average$Contig_Count_Average))
```

and then use the `ggplot` code.

```
p2 <- ggplot(contig_count_average, mapping = aes(x = reorder(Genome_Type, 
         Contig_Count_Average), Contig_Count_Average, fill = Genome_Type))  + 
         xlab("Genome") +
         ylab("Contig No.") + 
         ggtitle("Contig Count per Genome Distribution") +
         geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
         theme(text = element_text(size=20),
         axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) +
         guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Genome Type")) +
         coord_flip() +
         theme_bw() +
         scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,2835), expand = c(0, 0)) +
         scale_x_discrete(labels = abbreviate)

p2
```

[image]

Also note that you can use `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for :D